# What was the impact of the moderation strike on site activity?

Tags: discussion, moderation-strike

During the last several weeks, as the strike was going on, it *felt* as if there was significantly less activity on the site, with several active contributors electing to not vote, edit, or Q&A.

The strike was announced on June 5th with the [open letter](https://openletter.mousetail.nl/), and ended with a [result of negotiations](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/391847/moderation-strike-results-of-negotiations) on August 2nd (acknowledging that individuals may still elect to continue engaging less after that).

Does anyone know what the quantitative impact of this was? How did the this period of about eight weeks differ from, say the same length period prior to this (to avoid larger, long term trends unduly influencing the comparison), or to the same period the year before (to avoid things like summer vacations impacting the comparison)? For example,

- how many fewer questions and answers did we have per week?
- how many fewer closures and reopens?
- how many fewer comments, edits?
- how many fewer votes?

Comment: feel free to use some of the queries from https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/387302/997587 to look at questions and answers. When querying SEDE for closures (`PostHistory` table), it might take some time to wait for the effect of roomba to pass to get a more normalized picture.

Comment: Several people noted that RPG SE chat felt pretty dead.

Answer (score 1):

I'll add to this over time if I have time to run more queries, thank you @starball for the link to the page of SEDE queries, extremely helpful.

| Topic | Strike Period | Year ago Period | Prior Period | % of Year Ago | % of Prior |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Questions | 276 | 382 | 385 | 72% | 72% |
| Answers | 592 | 908 | 871 | 65% | 68% |
| Tag Wiki & Excerpt | 5 | 44 | 6 | 11% | 83% |

The Tag Wiki Activity seems to have been unusually high a year ago.

Comment: about a year ago we had some larger retagging things iirc.

Comment: It is not totally clear to me what you mean with "Year ago period": are you considering the same time interval of the strike 1 year ago? What do you mean by prior period?

Comment: Yes, the same date range, just in 2022, instead of 2023 as described in the question.

Comment: And prior period?

Comment: As per the qeustion, this is the window of same number of days just before the strike period.